# What is wrong with my basic ReactJS app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a basic [ReactJS app using this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/getting-started-with-reactjs).

Currently I have a blank page, and when I type out `MessageBox`, the name of my component, I get the following error.

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Playing with ReactJS">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Playing with ReactJS</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- container node -->
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="bower_components/react/react.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/react/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        /** @jsx React.DOM */
        var MessageBox = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return (
                    <h1>Hello, World</h1>
                );
            }  
        });

        React.renderComponent(
            <MessageBox/>,
            document.getElementById('app'),
            function () {
                console.log('after render');
            }
        )
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

```
 /**
  * React v0.14.7
  */
```

Comment: @Andrew Hendrie, what kind of edit is this? Why do you capitalize some common words?

Comment: try using `ReactDOM.render` instead of `React.renderComponent`. The tutorial you're using seems to be outdated.

Comment: @Road I just tried that too, still nothing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The `renderComponent` function has been deprecated.**

You can use `ReactDOM.render()` instead of `React.renderComponent()`.

You new file should look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Playing with ReactJS">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Playing with ReactJS</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- container node -->
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="bower_components/react/react.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/react/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        /** @jsx React.DOM */
        var MessageBox = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return (
                    <h1>Hello, World</h1>
                );
            }  
        });

        ReactDOM.render(
            <MessageBox/>,
            document.getElementById('app'),
            function () {
                console.log('after render');
            }
        );
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also - extract that function into a separate js file.

Here's a [good (up to date) tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) on this.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried that, and also copied the updated markup, still nothing :(

Comment: see update - ReactDOM.render and a semicolon after that function

Comment: Nothing still... hmm I think @thorn may be on to something

Comment: see edit on extracting that code to a separate js file

Answer (score 3):

The browser doesn't understand JSX. You need to convert it to JavaScript somehow for it to start working. You can do it either by moving the code to a separate `.jsx` file and setting up some tool like Babel to compile it, or you can use JSXTransformer to run the transformation (JSX -> JS) in the browser. However, [JSXTransformer has been deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html#jsxtransformer) and might not support some recent addition to the JSX syntax (e.g. [valueless attributes](https://github.com/facebook/jsx/pull/49)).

Comment: LOL! I wondered how `<script type="text/jsx">` would work, wish it threw an error or something, and wish the Author of the tut had mentioned that, he doesn't do that anywhere. Looking into how to do this now. +1

Comment: The browser doesn't execute the content of the `script` elements that have `type` other than `text/javascript`. It's up to the loaded JS code to decide what to do with them.